# Where do I find the Control+Up key on my Sony Vaio computer?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, sony-vaio

On a Sony Vaio, I can't find a "Control + Up key" required for moving an online task. Where do I find it?

Comment: Huh?  Are you saying your keyboard doesn't have a Ctrl or an Up key?  Like physically doesn't have them?  Did they maybe fall off?  **What on earth is your question?**

Comment: [Not sure if serious or trollin'](http://troll.me/images/futurama-fry/not-sure-if-serious-or-trolling.jpg)

Comment: FYI if you're German then press Strg and the Up arrow button

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try one of these:

1. You can press <kbd>Control + Up</kbd> if you have that key.
2. You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> press <kbd>Up</kbd> as an alternative.
3. You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> press <kbd>⬆</kbd> as a second alternative.
4. You can install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and bind a key to `Send Keys {Control Down}{Up}{Control Up}`.

Here are the keys...

[image: keys on vaio laptop]

Or you could opt for this unique work in progress of a Microsoft keyboard...

[image: control+up keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Those of us who have used computers for a long time occasionally forget how peculiar they are and how bizarre the language that has grown up around computers.

When people say "press the Ctrl + up key" they mean

- Hold down the key labelled "Ctrl" with your left index finger.
- Without releasing the "Ctrl key", with your right hand's index finger, press once, the key labelled with an upward pointing arrow.
- Release the key labelled "Ctrl".

Other keys labelled "Ctrl" can also be used, as can other fingers.